# OpenApi (Swagger) with AWS ECS integration - expose all operations

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs, openapi

I use AWS ECS for my server (multiple microservers) in some website, and I use API Gateway + OpenApi to define the routes and to integrate them with the ECS microservers.

Every path prefix should integrate with different ECS and direct all subpaths to there.

Is there a way to use some regex in OpenApi to integrate it with ALL paths and operations under some path?

This is how I'm defining the path for single path and single operation:

OpenApi:

```
openapi: "3.0.1"
info:
  title:
    Fn::Sub: "${EnvironmentName}-api"
  version: 0.0.1
paths:
  /api/project:
    get:
      responses:
        default:
          description: "Default response for GET"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        payloadFormatVersion: "1.0"
        connectionId:
          Fn::ImportValue:
            Fn::Sub: ${EnvironmentName}:HttpApiVPCLink
    type: "http_proxy"
    httpMethod: "ANY"
    uri:
      Fn::ImportValue:
        Fn::Sub: ${EnvironmentName}:DiscoveryService-microserver-1
    connectionType: "VPC_LINK"

  /api/item:
    get:
      responses:
        default:
          description: "Default response for GET"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        payloadFormatVersion: "1.0"
        connectionId:
          Fn::ImportValue:
            Fn::Sub: ${EnvironmentName}:HttpApiVPCLink
        type: "http_proxy"
        httpMethod: "ANY"
        uri:
          Fn::ImportValue:
            Fn::Sub: ${EnvironmentName}:DiscoveryService-microserver-2
        connectionType: "VPC_LINK"
```

So in this code:

- Route `/api/project` with operation get will use microserver1 and
- Route `/api/item` with operation get will use microserver2

But what I need is every route with prefix `/api/project` and any operation will use microserver1,
for example - post operation or route `/api/project/{id}` should also use the microserver1 without additional definition in the OpenApi file

Is there any way to define something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the proxy integration. [See Documentations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html)

When you use the proxy integration, your all sub API will be proxied to the targets.